# Появляется странный пустой файл в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

вот с таким именем, удаляю появляется, что за бред и откуда?
**0@@X@8@!@@@@@��@@@@��**

Comment: Не нужно истерики. Покажите информацию о файле, в какой именно директории и т.д.

Comment: Где появляется? Что говорит `fuser` и `lsof` на него? В выводе 16 байт, если вам что-то это говорит... Причём судя по кускам это не имя файла, а содержимое чего-то бинарного.

Comment: /home/пользователь.

Comment: А как ими пользоваться, что они должны выдать?

Comment: У меня подобный файл создаёт Intellij Idea, но это на довольно старой ubuntu

Comment: @Roman тогда  все норм у меня тоже стоит PHP Storm

Comment: Прикольный вопрос) а не прбовали посмотреть, что там? cat, strings, vim emacs? если волнует призхождение, попробуйте в cron на каждую секунду добавить lsof.